# 502 Bad Gateway after login

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4, php-7

I set up both Laravel 4.2 and 5.2 project on Digital Ocean VPS. The v5.2 project  works normally but the v4.2 one shows an error "502 Bad Gateway" after login. If I logout the account, everything works ok.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx, Mysql, PHP 7 with fpm (I setup nginx virtual host properly `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`). I use Entrust for authentication and authorization.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: After configuring FPM, did you restart nginx and FPM? (`sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php7.0-fpm reload`)

Comment: Yes, of course. The problem occurs only after login. If I don't login, every page is ok.